# Take the kerning of a font to make it the kerning of another one

Tags: fonts, kerning

The `charter` font from `mathdesign` has poor kerning while the [`Charter` font by SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=CharisSIL_download)
is better. The problem is that the bold face of SIL is really bold and I prefer the one from `mathdesign`. Actually, even the non-bold face is thick compared to `mathdesign`. I can also use `mathdesign` with pdflatex and the `microtype` to get a good kerning in french. SIL is not usable with pdflatex I believe. So is it possible to take the kerning of SIL and make `mathdesign` use this one?

Note: There is also an `xcharter` improving the kerning but the thickness is as with SIL.

My engines are lualatex and pdflatex to use microtype.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is it practical or something you are at all likely to actually want to do? Almost certainly not. However, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which at least shows your basic set up would nonetheless be useful. (We don't know which engine you are using or how you are using `charter` or anything.) Is SIL Charter metrically equivalent to charter? That is, are the dimensions of the glyphs identical? (For example, is the width of 'A' and 'r' and 'Q' the same? This seems doubtful if their thicknesses differ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use `lualatex` you can define your own kerning via a feature file (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html). An example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{texgyrebonum.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern { 
  pos a u -90;
  pos u s -60; 
  pos e r -70; } kern;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic]{TeX Gyre Bonum}

\begin{document}
{\huge exhauster} (without)\par
\addfontfeatures{FeatureFile=texgyrebonum.fea}
{\huge exhauster} (with)
\end{document}
```

[image]